# F# using a class instance's member functions

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a connection to open a database over ODBC.  I cannot figure out how to execute an objects member functions. The code:

```
let DbConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection()

DbConnection.open
```

The errors I get are:   `Missing qualification after '.'`

or sometimes:   `unexpected identifier in implementation file`

Does anybody know what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Have you tried `DbConnection.Open()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you wanted something like this:

```
let dbConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection()
dbConnection.Open()
```

The problems are:

- F# is case sensitive so you need `Open` rather than `open` (also `open` is a language keyword, so if you wanted to use it as a name, you'd have to write ``` ``open`` ``` - the double back-tick is a way to refer to reserved names)
- `Open` is a function, so if you want to call it you need to give it an argument. You can treat it as a function value too and write, say, `let f = dbConnection.Open`
- I also changed your naming to use `camelCase` for variables, which is the standard F# way

Comment: k thanks. that works, also as a tangent have you read the recent oleg paper on reflection without remorse, I read a couple of your recent blog posts, and the update monad paired with oleg's reflection implementation might be cool in f#